# There's something wrong in converting decimal to binary

Tags: dart

```
int main(){
    int input;
    int bin = 0, i = 1;
    print("Please input a number");
    input = num.parse(stdin.readLineSync());
    while(input > 0)
    {
        bin = bin + (input % 2)*i;
        input = input/2;
        i = i * 10;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

It returned infinite numbers.

Comment: Division returns a double, which you are assigning to an int. What editor are you using? A text editor with Dart support should have given you a  static type warning.

Comment: I'm using Sublime Text 3

Comment: Are you using the Dart package? https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Dart

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to take care of double to int conversion: `input = (input/2).floor()`

See this working code:

```
void main() {
  int input;
  int bin = 0, i = 1;
  input = 5;
  while(input > 0)
  {
      bin = bin + (input % 2)*i;
      input = (input/2).floor();
      i = i * 10;
  }

  print(bin);
}
```

Comment: Since `input` is an int, this is a good use case for integer division: `input ~/= 2;`. No conversion needed.

Comment: Another option is to use `input >>= 1;` to remove the lowest bit.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a version of the above function that:

- uses the integer division
- with a ternary conditional operator, avoids the conversion to string.
- sets the most significant bit to the left (`bin = (dec % 2) + bin`; which is what most people expects, but is not what the original snippet did)

```dart
String dec2bin(int dec) {
  var bin = '';
  while (dec > 0) {
    bin = (dec % 2 == 0 ? '0' : '1') + bin;
    dec ~/= 2;
  }
  return bin;
}
```

P.S: But, of course, one can simply write:

```dart
var bin = num.toRadixString(2);
```

There is no real need to write your own `dec2bin` function.

Answer (score 0):

As the int result can become easily big in length and the max int value in dart is 2e53 (and much less if you compile to web).  it's better to change the approach and return as a String.

```
  String dec2bin(int decimal) {
    String bin = '';
    while (decimal > 0) {
      bin = bin + (decimal % 2).toString();
      decimal = (decimal / 2).floor();
    }
    return bin;
  }

   print(dec2bin(132070242815));
```

Result: 1111111110011111111111111111110101111

Answer (score 0):

```
//number is always in int
static String decimalToBinary(int number) {
  return number.toRadixString(2);
}

//binary is always in string
static int binaryToDecimal(String binary) {
  return int.parse(binary, radix: 2);
}
```